# Stop the function from changing the original list

Tags: python, pygame

im making a bingo game with challenges using pygame... 
the thing is i got a function "challengeGeneretor" and original list of challenges with len of 35 items and after i using the function, it removes from the original list instead from the list i made in the function (i tried without before) and that makes an error when im trying to generate a new random challenges for the bingo. (it works on the first generate)

here is the function:

```
    def challengesGeneretor(self, challenges, board):
        challenges1 = challenges
        for n, i in enumerate(board):
            for j in range(len(i)):
                x = random.randint(0, len(challenges1) - 1)
                board[n][j] = challenges1[x]
                challenges1.remove(challenges1[x])
        challenges1 = challenges      # just me trying things
        return board
```

and the events function... dunno if its a part of the problem

```
    def playing_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                selected = self.mouseOnGrid()
                buttonClick = self.mouseOnButton()
                if selected:
                    self.selected.add(selected)
                if buttonClick:
                    self.selected = set()
                    self.grid = testboard     # "testboard" = empty board
                    self.grid = self.challengesGeneretor(challenges, testboard)
```

here the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "\app_class.py", line 25, in run
    self.playing_events()
  File "\pygames\app_class.py", line 47, in playing_events
    self.grid = self.challengesGeneretor(challenges, testboard)
  File "\app_class.py", line 146, in challengesGeneretor
    x = random.randint(0, len(challenges1) - 1)
  File "\random.py", line 222, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "\random.py", line 200, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

Any help will be SUPER appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `challenges1 = challenges` does not create a copy, it merely assigns the object being referred to by `challenges` to `challenges1`, so now you have two names referring to the same object.

Comment: Simple way to create a copy of a list in python would be `challenges1 = challenges[:]`

Comment: oh i didnt know this... should i make an empty list and append item by item to the new list ? or there is another way to make a copy?

Comment: Thanks working great!!

Comment: More explicitly `challenges1 = challenges.copy()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`challenges1 = challenges` does not create a new array in the memory, it passes a memory address to the new variable (check pointers). It works like that with complex data structures, like arrays.

If you want a copy of the original list, create a function that creates an empty list, and copy the elements of the original one into the newly created.

Comment: It's easy to copy a list with something like:   `copied_list = original_list[:]`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to understand the principle of shallow copy. [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

And you might want to ask yourself if you really want to work on a copy, as when the list gets big, performance could be an issue.

Comment: That wasn't a shallow copy, it wasn't a copy at all